# Replace portion of string in many records with a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with a varchar filed that has many records like:

```
folder/subfolder_1/file_xpto
folder/subfolder_2/file_abc
folder/subfolder_3/file_123
folder/subfolder_4/file_xyz
```

I would like in a single query to remove the portion of the string "/subfolder_x" so in the end it will be:

```
folder/file_xpto
folder/file_abc
folder/file_123
folder/file_xyz
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: is the string format consistent?

Comment: YEs it is. However there are others like folder_b/abc/ddd but I only need to do this to the ones with folder/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `substring_index` to get the first and last substrings and concatenate them using `concat_ws`.

```
select concat_ws('/',substring_index(colname,'/',1),substring_index(colname,'/',-1))
from tablename
where colname like 'folder/%'
```